# How to create multiple IP addresses to a single NIC in Azure VMSS

Tags: ip-address, azure-virtual-network, azure-vm-scale-set

I created an **azure-vm-scale-set** through the portal and attached a single NIC.
How can I add IP Configurations(secondery IP address)to that NIC?

Comment: Any more updates for the question? Do you solve the problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the IP configuration via the Azure CLI command to the NIC:

```
az vmss update --resource-group groupName --name vmssName --add virtualMachineProfile.networkProfile.networkInterfaceConfigurations[0].ipConfigurations '{"name": "config-2", "primary": false, "privateIpAddressVersion": "IPv4", "publicIpAddressConfiguration": null, "subnet": {"id": "resourceId", "resourceGroup": "groupName"}}'
```

Then upgrade all the instances, this will apply the new configuration to the instances. Then you need to manually update the network setting inside the instance following the steps [Add IP addresses to a VM operating system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-portal#os-confighttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-portal#os-config).